# Updating nVidia Driver to 295.53 in 12.04

Tags: nvidia, kernel

I custom build Linux kernels. I enjoy tinkering with the settings to try and slim down the build as much as possible.

But here is the problem: The version of the nVidia drivers in oneric is too low to support Linux 3.4 (see this bug: https://launchpad.net/bugs/993506)

So in order to use linux 3.4 on my computer, I have several options:

1) Use the source code hack (moving a file from arm/ to x86/) (I'd rather not, as this may create problems later)

2) Install the driver using nVidia's installer (Not really a good option as package conflicts would occur (e.g. warzone2100 won't install because the driver package isn't installed))

3) Find some way of installing the ubuntu 295.53 package on this system (either by installing the package directly from the launchpad link, building the package or through backports (preferable))

So, I'm assuming #3 is the most *correct* way of doing it, and if so, what would be the best way then?

PS: I'm not fussed about having it automatically update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to build the driver yourself, try use swat-x's ppa

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates/?field.series_filter=oneiric

in other words:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

Comment: Just discovered that before refreshing..... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

3 is the most appropriate option.

1. Temporarily add `precise` source repo to `sources.list`
2. `apt-get source 295.52-driver-package-whatever-that-is`
3. Try to build with `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`
4. Succeed and get deb packages, or get dependency error messages, in which case attempt to resolve and `goto` 3.

Comment: I tried downloading the source from launchpad, but it just had the .run files that nv distributes. Would this source be different?

Comment: Nope - browsing the archive manually (http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-updates/) shows the same source file that I downloaded previously (just a .tar.gz of the run files.)

Comment: Also of note - the diff file implies that there is a standard debain/control file and such, but there is none in the archive. The archive's md5 matches that of the one on launchpad.

Comment: Sorry, this sounds like the proprietary drivers, in which. se just install the precise debs/binaries and update. The "source" will of course fail to build.

Comment: I looked at the bug, it's the common pm_message header issue (I build custom kernels too). The workaround is fine --  the arm versions are not a problem, since this is basically a file renaming issue. Alternately, try the deb frOm
nvidia-graphics-drivers-updates (295.53-0ubuntu1) quantal

Answer (score 0):

Add `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/q-lts-backport` and `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`, update, install the kernel, manually load `nvidia-current-updates_295.53-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` per izx ... done and done.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your answer to include information on how to perform each of these steps.